# fancybox and transparent background image

Tags: jquery, css, image, png, fancybox

I am using fancybox to show a png image... it is transparent background, but a border appears when I run the code

How can I remove or hide that border around my png image (look the screenshot)?

[image]

my css

```
.fancybox-content {
       background: transparent;
        
    }
```

my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox.open('<div class="message"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="fotoTiendas/Captura.jpg" id="imgx"></a></div>');
        
    });
```

thanks a lot

Comment: .fancybox-content {
       border:none !important;
        
    }

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work

Comment: .fancybox-content { outline: none !important; }

Comment: :( it still doesn't work... thanks..... by the way if I remove <a></a> tags, the border desseapears... but I need to link the image... what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus {
  outline: outline of your choice
}
```

from MDN Web Docs:

> Accessibility concerns
> Assigning outline a value of 0 or none will remove the browser's default focus style. If an element can be interacted with it must have a visible focus indicator. Provide obvious focus styling if the default focus style is removed.